# How to connect to a REST service that needs Windows client authentication from Java?

Tags: java, windows, rest, kerberos, ntlmv2

I want to access a REST service from Java. The service runs under Windows and uses probably a "default" authentication mechanism. I was told it was Kerberos with a fallback to NTLM. I am able to access the service by a plain HTTPS GET request using Firefox (works with HttpRequester, too) - without specifying any credentials explicitely (obviously my Windows account is used).

How can I access the service from Java? A naive attempt to read using java.net.URL fails with status code 400.

Comment: org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-win:4.5.3 looks promising.

Comment: httpclient-win works, but I didn't find out why or how yet.

Comment: Hi; If we've answered your question please mark it as such which will verify it to others in the community; otherwise please let us know if any.

Answer (score 0):

Even the JDK (JVM implementation of Oracle) offers this, you may have a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jgss/lab/part6.html

Comment: The Oracle JVM is propably not an option, as OpenJDK is used on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

This provides the high-level steps for the solution.  You'll need Active Directory in order to leverage Kerberos with Windows.  Then what you will do is use Java Spring Security for Kerberos in order to access the REST service from Java.  The below are the more concrete steps.

1. The Java Spring Security for Kerberos library will do the heavy lifting for you, this provides a class to inject a Kerberos configuration into the HTTP client: `org.springframework.security.kerberos.client.KerberosRestTemplate`
2. You define some Kerberos properties within a client configuration .properties file.  Here's the most important snippet from the file with respect to Kerberos:

> ```
> KERBEROS.FLAG=Y
> KERBEROS.DEBUG=true
> SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PRINCIPAL = HTTP/some.hostname@YOUR.REALM
> KEYTAB_LOCATION = file:///C:/path/to/filename.keytab
> KDC = server.fqdn.name
> KDC_DOMAIN = YOUR.REALM
> KRB5 = file:///C:/path/to/krb5.conf
> ```

EDIT:

Kerberos keytabs are not required with a Java client on a Windows AD domain-joined machine.  Since you want to use the credentials of the person who is running the Java program, you wouldn't use a keytab (since the keytab itself contains only one credential).

[Refer to the official Spring Security Website](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/extensions/krb/)

Comment: Hi @Gustave; I've made an important edit to this question,  If it answered your question please mark it as such so that it may help others; otherwise please let know if any

Comment: Hi T-Heron, sorry, but I simply don't understand your answer. What do you mean with "leverage"? All the environment is already set up and I have very little influence on that. httpclient-win does the job, without any visible heavy lifting, but as usual when something works, finding out why it does so is of lower priority.